# Unable to Change element's value

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to change an element's value  from "false" to "true"

```
<ItemMaster>
        <ItemMasterHeader>
            <ItemID>
                <ID>ASSET1</ID>
            </ItemID>
            <DisplayID>ASSET1</DisplayID>
            <GTIN/>
            <ServiceIndicator xmlns="">false</ServiceIndicator>
            <Description>AC SPLIT WALL 1.5 PKPANASONICS</Description>
            <Note/>
            <Classification>
                <Codes>
                    <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1" xmlns:my="http://schema.com/OAGIS/2">Purchased</Code>
                    <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="2">4ET</Code>
                    <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="3">*</Code>
                </Codes>
            </Classification>
            <HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
            <TrackingIndicator>false</TrackingIndicator>
```

I use the following XSL :

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template
        match="//my:SyncItemMaster/my:DataArea/my:ItemMaster/my:ItemMasterHeader/my:TrackingIndicator">
            <xsl:value-of select="true" />
    </xsl:template>
```

But what I get is this :

```
    <ItemMaster>
        <ItemMasterHeader>
            <ItemID>
                <ID>ASSET1</ID>
            </ItemID>
            <DisplayID>ASSET1</DisplayID>
            <GTIN/>
            <ServiceIndicator xmlns="">false</ServiceIndicator>
            <Description>AC SPLIT WALL 1.5 PKPANASONICS</Description>
            <Note/>
            <Classification>
                <Codes>
                    <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1" xmlns:my="http://schema.com/OAGIS/2">Purchased</Code>
                    <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="2">4ET</Code>
                    <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="3">*</Code>
                </Codes>
            </Classification>
            <HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
```

Instead, The  element is totally missing.

What possibly went wrong here? it seems a very basic function, but I don't know why it is missing.

UPDATE :

I have tried to add some code to the XSLT :

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template
        match="//my:SyncItemMaster/my:DataArea/my:ItemMaster/my:ItemMasterHeader/my:TrackingIndicator">
            <xsl:element name="TrackingIndicator">
            <xsl:value-of select="true" />
            </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

But now the result becomes like this :

```
    <ItemMaster>
        <ItemMasterHeader>
            <ItemID>
                <ID>ASSET1</ID>
            </ItemID>
            <DisplayID>ASSET1</DisplayID>
            <GTIN/>
            <ServiceIndicator xmlns="">false</ServiceIndicator>
            <Description>AC SPLIT WALL 1.5 PKPANASONICS</Description>
            <Note/>
            <Classification>
                <Codes>
                    <Code listID="Item Types" sequence="1" xmlns:my="http://schema.com/OAGIS/2">Purchased</Code>
                    <Code listID="Item Groups" sequence="2">4ET</Code>
                    <Code listID="MRO Classes" sequence="3">*</Code>
                </Codes>
            </Classification>
            <HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
            <TrackingIndicator xmlns=""/>
```

It is still not like what I am hoping (TrackingIndicator) true (TrackingIndicator)

Thank you so much for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the template as below (you may need to take care of any applicable namespace).

```
<xsl:template match="TrackingIndicator">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="'true'" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Instead of specifying the entire XPath, you can mention only the element name in the template match. For setting the value, `true` should be specified within `single quotes` as a string.

Output

```
<TrackingIndicator>true</TrackingIndicator>
```